# How to show that $p(t|x,\mathbf x,\mathbf t)= \int p(t|x,\mathbf w)p(\mathbf w|\mathbf x, \mathbf t)d\mathbf w $

Tags: probability, machine-learning, pattern-recognition

The following paragraph is approximately cited from Bishop's book, [Pattern Recognition and
Machine Learning](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cmbishop/prml/).

> In curve fitting problem, we have training data $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf t$, along with a new test point $x$, and our goal is to predict the value of $t$. We therefore wish to evaluate the predictive distribution $p(t|x,\mathbf x,\mathbf t)$.
>  Where the predictive distribution is:
>
> $$p(t|x,\mathbf x,\mathbf t)= \int p(t|x,\mathbf w)p(\mathbf w|\mathbf x, \mathbf t)d\mathbf w $$ 
> and $\mathbf w$ is the weight vector of the polynomial.

My question is how I can prove the above relation? I know Bayes' rule and sum and product rules of probability. Specifically I know for example $p(a)=\int p(a,b)db=\int p(a|b)p(b)db$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Putting $a=t$, $b=\mathbf w$, $c=(x,\mathbf x, \mathbf t)$ into $p(a|c)=\int p(a|b,c)p(b|c)db$ yields:

$$ p(t|x,\mathbf x,\mathbf t)=\int p(t|\mathbf w, x, \mathbf x, \mathbf t)p(\mathbf w|x,\mathbf x,\mathbf t)d\mathbf w\tag1$$

If we impose the assumption that $(x,t)$ is independent of $(\mathbf x,\mathbf t)$ given $\mathbf w$, then it follows that
$$p(t|\mathbf w, x, \mathbf x, \mathbf t)=p(t|x,\mathbf w)\;.$$
It remains to explain how  $p(\mathbf w|x,\mathbf x,\mathbf t)$ became $p(\mathbf w|\mathbf x,\mathbf t)$. In general this is not true without additional assumptions. We can finesse the issue in this case because we are treating $x$ as a fixed test point, i.e., we are not putting a distribution on $x$, so one can just as well omit $x$ from all the equations.

Alternatively, we can bypass the need for proof by using (1) to motivate the *definition* of the predictive distribution as
$$
p(t|x,\mathbf x,\mathbf t):= \int p(t|x,\mathbf w)p(\mathbf w|\mathbf x, \mathbf t)d\mathbf w\;.
$$

If you jump ahead in Bishop, you'll see that a similar equation (3.57) in section 3.3.2 omits $x$ from the definition of the predictive distribution:
$$p(t|\mathbf t,\alpha,\beta)=\int p(t|w,\beta)p(w|\mathbf t,\alpha,\beta)\,dw$$

Comment: You have written: "It remains to explain how $p(w|x,X,T)$ became $p(w|X,T)$. In general this is not true without additional assumptions." But I think it is clear, because **$w$** is obtained by **$X$** and **$T$**. So **$w$** is conditionally independent of $x$ given $X$ and **$T$**. Isn't it?

Comment: I think in the second paragraph you mean $t$ is independent of $ ( \textbf{x}, \textbf{t} ) $ given $x$ and $ \textbf{w} $ ?